# Get number of an index of an infinite number 1121231234...n

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Q: If we join these blocks of numbers, we come up with an infinite sequence which
starts with 112123123412345123456.... The list is infinite.

You will be given an number (n) and your task will be to return the element at
that index in the sequence, where 1 ≤ n ≤ 10^18. Assume the indexes start with
1, not 0. For example:

solve(1) = 1, because the first character in the sequence is 1. There is no
index 0.
solve(2) = 1, because the second character is also 1.
solve(3) = 2, because the third character is 2.

My algorithm is way to inefficient, I just create the number until index n is reached. It is a task from codewars.com.

I wonder if anyone has a better idea.
My code:

```
def solve(n): 
    st = ""
    numb = ""
    i = 1
    r = 0
    running = True
    while running:
        numb = numb + str(i)
        st = st + numb
        try:
            r = st[n - 1]
            return r
        except:
            i += 1
```

with an number like "999999999999999999" it needs way too much time to calculate.
If you want to test:

```
print(solve(999999999999999999))
```

Comment: no idea what this should accomplish. First hint for speedup, dont use string concattenation. Put the single strings into a list and return ``.join(yourlist) if you need the concattenated string.

Comment: Okay I postet a link with the exact task. I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: It's not just the time. It's the memory. `r[999999999999999999-1]` will exist when `r` has a length of 1000 petaelements (minus 1). Like petabytes. Somehow I doubt you have that much memory in your machine. You will need some other approach for sure.

Comment: Don't post a link. Describe what you want to do. I shouldn't have to go to another site to understand your question.

Comment: I actually did it on purpose to keep my post easily readable.

Comment: Added code accepted by the online judge to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You start by adding 1 digit numbers: 1, 112, 112123, ... up to 9 at position 45.  That gets you up to a known position in the infinite number.  Then you add two digit numbers, and you can calculate where you add 99 into the infinite number.  Repeat for three digit numbers, four digit numbers so you can set up a series of boundaries in the infinite number with known starting points up to 10^18.

Given an `n` find where the given `n` lies between two precalculated boundaries.  Work forwards, or backwards, from the nearest boundary to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

We have three types of structures that we would like to be able to search on, (1) the sequence of concatenating `d`-digit numbers, for example, single digit:

```
123456...
```

or 3-digit:

```
100101102103
```

(2) the rows in a section,
where each section builds on the previous section added to a prefix. For example, section 1:

```
1
12
123
...
```

or section 3:

```
1234...10111213...100
1234...10111213...100102
1234...10111213...100102103
<---- prefix ---->
```

and (3) the full sections, although the latter we can just enumerate since they grow exponentially and help build our section prefixes. For (1), we can use simple division if we know the digit count; for (2), we can binary search.

Here's Python code that also answers the big ones:

```py
def getGreatest(n, d, prefix):
  rows = 9 * 10**(d - 1)
  triangle = rows * (d + rows * d) // 2
  l = 0
  r = triangle
 
  while l < r:
    mid = l + ((r - l) >> 1)
    triangle = mid * prefix + mid * (d + mid * d) // 2
    prevTriangle = (mid-1) * prefix + (mid-1) * (d + (mid-1) * d) // 2
    nextTriangle = (mid+1) * prefix + (mid+1) * (d + (mid+1) * d) // 2
 
    if triangle >= n:
      if prevTriangle < n:
        return prevTriangle
      else:
        r = mid - 1
    else:
      if nextTriangle >= n:
        return triangle
      else:
        l = mid
 
  return l * prefix + l * (d + l * d) // 2
 
def solve(n):
  debug = 1
  d = 0
  p = 0.1
  prefixes = [0]
  sections = [0]
 
  while sections[d] < n:
    d += 1
    p *= 10
    rows = int(9 * p)
    triangle = rows * (d + rows * d) // 2
    section = rows * prefixes[d-1] + triangle
    sections.append(sections[d-1] + section)
    prefixes.append(prefixes[d-1] + rows * d)
 
  section = sections[d - 1]
 
  if debug:
    print("section: %s" % section)
 
  n = n - section
  rows = getGreatest(n, d, prefixes[d - 1])
 
  if debug:
    print("rows: %s" % rows)
 
  n = n - rows
 
  d = 1
 
  while prefixes[d] < n:
    d += 1;
 
  if prefixes[d] == n:
    return 9;
 
  prefix = prefixes[d - 1]
 
  if debug:
    print("prefix: %s" % prefix)
 
  n -= prefix
 
  if debug:
    print((n, d, prefixes, sections))
 
  countDDigitNums = n // d
  remainder = n % d
 
  prev = 10**(d - 1) - 1
  num = prev + countDDigitNums
 
  if debug:
    print("num: %s" % num)
 
  if remainder:
    return int(str(num + 1)[remainder - 1])
  else:
    s = str(num);
    return int(s[len(s) - 1])
 
ns = [
  1, # 1
  2, # 1
  3, # 2
  100, # 1
  2100, # 2
  31000, # 2
  999999999999999999, # 4
  1000000000000000000, # 1
  999999999999999993, # 7
]
 
for n in ns:
  print(n)
  print(solve(n))
  print('')
```

Comment: I don't think this works without modification once you get to numbers with double digits. For example, after 123456789, the sequence continues 12345678910, which has 11 digits, not 10.

Comment: (Has been fixed.)

Answer (score 1):

The first idea is that you do not need the actual string, you just need the length of the hypothetical string which is generated already and then you need to produce the given element of the last substring

```
def solve(n):
  string=""
  i=1
  while len(string)<n:
    n-=len(string)
    string+=str(i)
    i+=1
  print("len:",len(string))
  return string[n-1]

print(solve(1))
print(solve(2))
print(solve(3))
print(solve(100))
print(solve(2100))
print(solve(31000))
#print(solve(999999999999999999))
#print(solve(1000000000000000000))
#print(solve(999999999999999993))
```

This one will correctly produce 1,1,2,1,2,2 for the first 6 tests, and also show that for getting the 31000th element, it needs to actually keep in memory a 411-character string. This still does not scale to the super-high variants, so we have to abandon generating the string at all, and use the same idea inside too: keeping track of length, and generate the result from sub-strings.

<strike>Will be back a bit later.</strike>
This one has a single actual string-conversion, offset and everything is done by math, but it still does not work for the large ones:

```
from math import log10,floor

def solve(n):
  length=0
  i=1
  while length<n:
    n-=length
    length+=floor(log10(i))+1
    i+=1
  print("len:",length)
  i=1
  length=1
  while length<n:
    n-=length
    i+=1
    length=floor(log10(i))+1
  return str(i)[n-1]

print(solve(1))
print(solve(2))
print(solve(3))
print(solve(100))
print(solve(2100))
print(solve(31000))
#print(solve(999999999999999999))
#print(solve(1000000000000000000))
#print(solve(999999999999999993))
```

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63314814/2034787) one example that answers the big ones.